# Featured image link on parent site

Tags: feature-request, featured-photo

On the parent site, where the featured image is shown, there is a link called "submit yours" that takes you to the meta site where you can upload an image and/or vote on images already submitted.

Would it make sense to re-label the link to say "submit yours, or vote for next week's image"?

That might drive more people to view the images and start voting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good suggestion. I have updated the language in the latest message.